# Is Romberg integration method implemented as weighted function values numerically correct?

Tags: numerics, integration, quadrature, numerical-limitations

I have to integrate expression `f(x) * g(x)` for many different functions `f` but just one `g`.

I want to integrate it as sum of weighted values of `f(x) * g(x)` instead of calculating the table.  Note that in Python I may write:

```
sum(w[i] * f(x[i]) * g(x[i]) for i in range(2 ** k + 1))
```

as:

```
wg = [w[i] * g(x[i]) for i in range(2 ** k + 1)]
sum(wg[i] * f(x[i]) for i in range(2 ** k + 1))
```

where `w[i]` are weights of function values used by the Romberg method which may be calculated like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import romb

w = romb(np.eye(2 ** k + 1))
```

Is such implementation of Romberg method safe?

(The question has been also asked at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659798/is-romberg-integration-method-implemented-as-weighted-function-values-numericall)

Comment: What's your `g` and what `are your `f`s? Do they have any desirable properties (e.g., smooth, polynomial, etc.)? What's your domain of integration?

Comment: `f` is arbitrary, but I can demand it to be smooth. `g` resembles $\frac{1}{|r|}$, where r is a distance to certain point in the integration domain. I can place that point as far as $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} dx$ from the nearest integration node, as well as exclude its neighbourhood from the integration.
The domain of integration is 3D, I use the Romberg method in each dimension.

Comment: The pole is not your only problem: You will also have to limit the function at infinity.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer I assume `f` is zero outside of domain covered by integration nodes.

Comment: that's a very bad assumption since the integral may really be infinity outside any bounded region.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer That is really not a problem, as I can just constrain `f` to comply with that assumption.

Comment: It is a problem because now your value depends on the position of the quadrature points. If your scheme contains a few points very far out, your value will be large.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer May you elaborate a bit more? I use Romberg's method with equally-spaced points in each dimension.

Comment: @abukaj, what Nico is saying that the support of the function `f` now depends on the convex hull of integration nodes. Those nodes will change as you change the order of the integration rule. So your problem is ill-posed. You should reformulate it, for example, as "let `f` have a compact support of unit cube, can I use Romberg integration as explained?". In that case, my answer would be yes.

Comment: @abukaj Your problem is like integrating the function `1/x` over `(0, infty)`. The true value is infinity, so it doesn't make sense to do quadrature here. You can of course still apply some quadrature rule (like Romberg) and it will return some value. If you take another method, you'll get another value unrelated to the first, so the values are meaningless.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas I can require `f` to have a compact support which is a subset of a cube. Is that enough, or does it have to be nonzero in the whole cube?

Comment: @NicoSchlömer I do not understand. Where does the `infty` come from? I want to calculate definite integral. If I limit support of `f` to a sphere of radius R arround the pole (within the convex hull of Romberg method's nodes), then for $g(r) = \frac{1}{|r|}$ the integral is bound by $\pm\max_{x: r(x) \le R} |f(x)| 4 \pi  \int_{0}^{R} r dr$, isn't it?
Also, I may exclude $r < R_0$ from the support of `f`.

Comment: Perhaps things will be easier to see if you could provide a typical example of an $f(x)$/$g(x)$ pair you are considering, along with the integration interval of interest. But let me warn you at the outset that if any of your functions have singularities (algebraic/logarithmic/whatever) at the endpoints or within the integration interval, all bets are off for Romberg.